# PLC data communication with a remote server

Tags: server, communication, plc

How can I interact with a PLC to send and receive data to/from a remote server(PC).

For example a robot that have a PLC and want to interact with a server that placed at near room with a wireless communication. 
Data must move all over the time. PLC sending the data to the server and server must sending back the result of computation on the data to PLC.

---

review : My PLC brand is Delta but its model has not been selected yet .

Comment: it depends on manufacturer but in general using OPC is a very common and system agnostic way to do that. see www.opcfoundation.org

Comment: Thank you dear @claptrap. Can you help me more about OPC and its implementation ?

Comment: What is your budget and reliability requirement?  Is this a project or is this for industry?

Comment: It's for industry but it's first experience for me. for budget we don't have much so if we can do this with less money is better. and we can contract for this work.

Comment: How much is 'less' money?  This is very relative.  Is $1000 too much?  Is $5000 too much?  Is $200 too much?  You could do something as simple as duct-tape a wireless router to the PLC if cheap is the objective.  The rest works out in the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common scenario is that the manufacturer provides an OPC server for the PLC. You should check their website once you know the model. Then it is just a matter for you to create an OPC client.

A good way to start is to get a free OPC server simulator like the one from [Matrikon](http://www.matrikonopc.com/products/opc-desktop-tools/index.aspx#2). It doesn't need any hardware. [OPC](http://www.opcfoundation.org) is a standard interface (although there are often some minor variations between manufacturers) - if you can get your client to work with the test server you can probably get it to work with the PLC.